# DataGrip MySQL stores emojis correctly but displays them as?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, datagrip

I'm having trouble viewing emojis in JetBrains DataGrip. In the main editor, emojis appear just fine, as well as in SQLite database viewer. In MySQL however, they appear as `?`

I've painstakingly had to figure out how to get emojis to store correctly in MySQL. I've followed many guides that tell you to make sure your server, client, connection, database, results, table, and column charsets are set to `utf8mb4` and the corresponding collations to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`. I've done this and still have the same results, i.e. MySQL displaying emojis as `?`

I double checked the variables and got these results:

```
character_set_client        utf8mb4
character_set_results       utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_server        utf8mb4
character_set_database      utf8mb4
collation_server            utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
collation_connection        utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
collation_database          utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

I then came across an answer on JetBrains' community that says you may have to cast the encoding like so:

```
UPDATE content SET data = (_utf8mb4 '') 
WHERE message_id = 45291;
```

But still, the error persisted. I then found this little gem to show the actual hex code value of the column:

```
SELECT col, HEX(col), LENGTH(col), CHAR_LENGTH(col)
FROM table WHERE id = 1;
```

The result was the following:

```
col     HEX(col)            LENGTH()    CHAR_LENGTH(col)
    F09F9899F09F9898    8           2
```

Well, sure enough, the data column shows the emojis. Note that these results are displayed in the console of DataGrip. And of course, the hex value corresponds to those emojis. I tested that with a [converter](http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php).

That's great! The hard part is done. MySQL is storing my data correctly.
But when I go to the actual table in DataGrip, I still see the value as `??`.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Here are the environment variables used in connecting to my server:

```
{
    "allowLoadLocalInfile": true,
    "allowMultiQueries": false,
    "allowNanAndInf": false,
    "allowUrlInLocalInfile": false,
    "alwaysSendSetIsolation": true,
    "autoClosePStmtStreams": false,
    "replicationConnectionGroup": "",
    "allowMasterDownConnections": false,
    "allowSlaveDownConnections": false,
    "readFromMasterWhenNoSlaves": false,
    "autoDeserialize": false,
    "autoGenerateTestcaseScript": false,
    "autoReconnect": true,
    "autoReconnectForPools": false,
    "blobSendChunkSize": 1048576,
    "autoSlowLog": true,
    "blobsAreStrings": false,
    "functionsNeverReturnBlobs": false,
    "cacheCallableStmts": false,
    "cachePrepStmts": false,
    "cacheResultsSetMetadata": false,
    "serverConfigCacheFactory": "com.mysql.jdbc.PerVmServerConfigCacheFactory",
    "cacheServerConfiguration": false,
    "callableStmtCacheSize": 100,
    "capitalizeTypeNames": true,
    "characterEncoding": "UTF-8",
    "characterSetResults": "UTF-8",
    "connectionAttributes": "",
    "clientInfoProvider": "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4CommentClientInfoProvider",
    "clobberStreamingResults": false,
    "clobCharacterEncoding": "",
    "compensateOnDuplicateKeyUpdateCounts": false,
    "connectionCollation": "",
    "connectionLifecycleInterceptors": "",
    "connectTimeout": 0,
    "continueBatchOnError": true,
    "createDatabaseIfNotExist": false,
    "defaultFetchSize": 0,
    "useServerPrepStmts": false,
    "dontTrackOpenResources": false,
    "dumpQueriesOnException": false,
    "dynamicCalendars": false,
    "elideSetAutoCommits": false,
    "emptyStringsConvertToZero": true,
    "emulateLocators": false,
    "emulateUnsupportedPstmts": true,
    "enablePacketDebug": false,
    "enableQueryTimeouts": true,
    "explainSlowQueries": false,
    "exceptionInterceptors": "",
    "failOverReadOnly": true,
    "gatherPerfMetrics": false,
    "generateSimpleParameterMetadata": false,
    "holdResultsOpenOverStatementClose": false,
    "includeInnodbStatusInDeadlockExceptions": false,
    "includeThreadDumpInDeadlockExceptions": false,
    "includeThreadNamesAsStatementComment": false,
    "ignoreNonTxTables": false,
    "initialTimeout": 2,
    "interactiveClient": false,
    "jdbcCompliantTruncation": true,
    "largeRowSizeThreshold": 2048,
    "loadBalanceStrategy": "random",
    "serverAffinityOrder": "",
    "loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout": 0,
    "loadBalancePingTimeout": 0,
    "loadBalanceValidateConnectionOnSwapServer": false,
    "loadBalanceConnectionGroup": "",
    "loadBalanceExceptionChecker": "com.mysql.jdbc.StandardLoadBalanceExceptionChecker",
    "loadBalanceSQLStateFailover": "",
    "loadBalanceSQLExceptionSubclassFailover": "",
    "loadBalanceEnableJMX": false,
    "loadBalanceHostRemovalGracePeriod": 15000,
    "loadBalanceAutoCommitStatementRegex": "",
    "loadBalanceAutoCommitStatementThreshold": 0,
    "localSocketAddress": "",
    "locatorFetchBufferSize": 1048576,
    "logger": "com.mysql.jdbc.log.StandardLogger",
    "logSlowQueries": false,
    "logXaCommands": false,
    "maintainTimeStats": true,
    "maxQuerySizeToLog": 2048,
    "maxReconnects": 3,
    "retriesAllDown": 120,
    "maxRows": -1,
    "metadataCacheSize": 50,
    "netTimeoutForStreamingResults": 600,
    "noAccessToProcedureBodies": false,
    "noDatetimeStringSync": false,
    "noTimezoneConversionForTimeType": false,
    "noTimezoneConversionForDateType": true,
    "cacheDefaultTimezone": true,
    "nullCatalogMeansCurrent": true,
    "nullNamePatternMatchesAll": true,
    "packetDebugBufferSize": 20,
    "padCharsWithSpace": false,
    "paranoid": false,
    "pedantic": false,
    "pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection": false,
    "populateInsertRowWithDefaultValues": false,
    "prepStmtCacheSize": 25,
    "prepStmtCacheSqlLimit": 256,
    "parseInfoCacheFactory": "com.mysql.jdbc.PerConnectionLRUFactory",
    "processEscapeCodesForPrepStmts": true,
    "profilerEventHandler": "com.mysql.jdbc.profiler.LoggingProfilerEventHandler",
    "profileSql": "",
    "profileSQL": false,
    "propertiesTransform": "",
    "queriesBeforeRetryMaster": 50,
    "queryTimeoutKillsConnection": false,
    "reconnectAtTxEnd": false,
    "relaxAutoCommit": false,
    "reportMetricsIntervalMillis": 30000,
    "requireSSL": false,
    "resourceId": "",
    "resultSetSizeThreshold": 100,
    "retainStatementAfterResultSetClose": false,
    "rewriteBatchedStatements": false,
    "rollbackOnPooledClose": true,
    "roundRobinLoadBalance": false,
    "runningCTS13": false,
    "secondsBeforeRetryMaster": 30,
    "selfDestructOnPingSecondsLifetime": 0,
    "selfDestructOnPingMaxOperations": 0,
    "replicationEnableJMX": false,
    "serverTimezone": "",
    "sessionVariables": ,
    "slowQueryThresholdMillis": 2000,
    "slowQueryThresholdNanos": 0,
    "socketFactory": "com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory",
    "socksProxyHost": "",
    "socksProxyPort": 1080,
    "socketTimeout": 0,
    "statementInterceptors": "",
    "strictFloatingPoint": false,
    "strictUpdates": true,
    "overrideSupportsIntegrityEnhancementFacility": false,
    "tcpNoDelay": true,
    "tcpKeepAlive": true,
    "tcpRcvBuf": 0,
    "tcpSndBuf": 0,
    "tcpTrafficClass": 0,
    "tinyInt1isBit": false,
    "traceProtocol": false,
    "treatUtilDateAsTimestamp": true,
    "transformedBitIsBoolean": false,
    "useBlobToStoreUTF8OutsideBMP": false,
    "utf8OutsideBmpExcludedColumnNamePattern": "",
    "utf8OutsideBmpIncludedColumnNamePattern": "",
    "useCompression": false,
    "useColumnNamesInFindColumn": false,
    "useConfigs": "",
    "useCursorFetch": false,
    "useDynamicCharsetInfo": true,
    "useDirectRowUnpack": true,
    "useFastIntParsing": true,
    "useFastDateParsing": true,
    "useHostsInPrivileges": true,
    "useInformationSchema": false,
    "useJDBCompliantTimezoneShift": false,
    "useLocalSessionState": false,
    "useLocalTransactionState": false,
    "useLegacyDatetimeCode": true,
    "sendFractionalSeconds": true,
    "useNanosForElapsedTime": false,
    "useOldAliasMetadataBehavior": false,
    "useOldUTF8Behavior": false,
    "useOnlyServerErrorMessages": true,
    "useReadAheadInput": true,
    "useSqlStateCodes": true,
    "useSSL": false,
    "useSSPSCompatibleTimezoneShift": false,
    "useStreamLengthsInPrepStmts": true,
    "useTimezone": false,
    "ultraDevHack": false,
    "useUnbufferedInput": true,
    "useUnicode": true,
    "useUsageAdvisor": false,
    "yearIsDateType": false,
    "zeroDateTimeBehavior": "convertToNull",
    "useJvmCharsetConverters": false,
    "useGmtMillisForDatetimes": false,
    "dumpMetadataOnColumnNotFound": false,
    "clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl": "",
    "trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl": "",
    "clientCertificateKeyStoreType": "JKS",
    "clientCertificateKeyStorePassword": "",
    "trustCertificateKeyStoreType": "JKS",
    "trustCertificateKeyStorePassword": "",
    "verifyServerCertificate": true,
    "useAffectedRows": false,
    "passwordCharacterEncoding": "",
    "maxAllowedPacket": -1,
    "authenticationPlugins": "",
    "disabledAuthenticationPlugins": "",
    "defaultAuthenticationPlugin": "com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.MysqlNativePasswordPlugin",
    "disconnectOnExpiredPasswords": true,
    "getProceduresReturnsFunctions": true,
    "detectCustomCollations": false,
    "serverRSAPublicKeyFile": "",
    "allowPublicKeyRetrieval": false,
    "dontCheckOnDuplicateKeyUpdateInSQL": false,
    "readOnlyPropagatesToServer": true,
    "enabledSSLCipherSuites": "",
    "enabledTLSProtocols": "",
    "enableEscapeProcessing": true
}
```

**EDIT**
Here are some screenshots to help you understand what I am seeing:

When I navigate to a record via the database table view (`?` in place of emoji):
[image: no-emoji]

When I execute a query to select the same record and view it in the console (the emoji is displayed as an emoji):
[image: emoji-console]

Comment: Show us how you connect to MySQL before the `SELECT`.  Are you displaying in HTML?  Is there a `<meta>` tag?

Comment: No, I'm just connecting through DataGrip directly.

Comment: @RickJames I just added the environment variables to my question. Not sure if it's helpful...

Comment: @MattR hi, have you ever figured this out?) Still face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

### Test environment

- MySQL `8.0.29`
- jdbc driver `8.0.25` and `8.0.29`
- DataGrip `2023.1.2`
- java `17`

### Reason

DataGrip itself uses jdbc driver to connect to MySQL server.

I am not sure which version of jdbc driver did you use.

In my case, I use `8.0.25` (driver version) which seems to be a watershed according to [Using Character Sets and Unicode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html), and then I reproduced your problem. Of course, I cannot also set `characterSetResults` to `utf8mb4` because the jdbc driver would throw an Exception.

So I read its [source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/8.0.25/src/main/core-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/NativeSession.java#L530-L579). As the code segment shown below (`com.mysql.cj.NativeSession#configureClientCharacterSet`), there is no solution which sets `characterSetResults` to `utf8mb4`.

```java
String onServer = this.protocol.getServerSession().getServerVariable("character_set_results");
if (characterSetResults.getValue() == null) {

  //
  // Only send if needed, if we're caching server variables we -have- to send, because we don't know what it was before we cached them.
  //
  if (onServer != null && onServer.length() > 0 && !"NULL".equalsIgnoreCase(onServer)) {
    sendCommand(this.commandBuilder.buildComQuery(null, "SET character_set_results = NULL"), false, 0);
    this.protocol.getServerSession().getServerVariables().put(ServerSession.LOCAL_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS, null);
  } else {
    this.protocol.getServerSession().getServerVariables().put(ServerSession.LOCAL_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS, onServer);
  }
} else {

  String charsetResults = characterSetResults.getValue();
  String mysqlEncodingName = null;

  if ("UTF-8".equalsIgnoreCase(charsetResults) || "UTF8".equalsIgnoreCase(charsetResults)) {
    mysqlEncodingName = "utf8";
  } else if ("null".equalsIgnoreCase(charsetResults)) {
    mysqlEncodingName = "NULL";
  } else {
    mysqlEncodingName = CharsetMapping.getMysqlCharsetForJavaEncoding(charsetResults.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH),
                            getServerSession().getServerVersion());
  }

  //
  // Only change the value if needed
  //

  if (mysqlEncodingName == null) {
    throw ExceptionFactory.createException(WrongArgumentException.class, Messages.getString("Connection.7", new Object[] { charsetResults }),
                            getExceptionInterceptor());
  }

  if (!mysqlEncodingName.equalsIgnoreCase(this.protocol.getServerSession().getServerVariable("character_set_results"))) {
    StringBuilder setBuf = new StringBuilder("SET character_set_results = ".length() + mysqlEncodingName.length());
    setBuf.append("SET character_set_results = ").append(mysqlEncodingName);

    sendCommand(this.commandBuilder.buildComQuery(null, setBuf.toString()), false, 0);

    this.protocol.getServerSession().getServerVariables().put(ServerSession.LOCAL_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS, mysqlEncodingName);

    // We have to set errorMessageEncoding according to new value of charsetResults for server version 5.5 and higher
    this.protocol.getServerSession().setErrorMessageEncoding(charsetResults);

  } else {
    this.protocol.getServerSession().getServerVariables().put(ServerSession.LOCAL_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS, onServer);
  }
}
```

The default value of `characterSetResults` in DataGrip Data Sources Advanced Dialog is `utf8` (DataGrip version: `2023.1.2`).

It will enter the

```java
if ("UTF-8".equalsIgnoreCase(charsetResults) || "UTF8".equalsIgnoreCase(charsetResults))
```

block when the code executes. However, the `utf8` is an alias of `utf8mb3` when MySQL version is bigger than 8.
So, the `character_set_results` variable is eventually set to `utf8mb3` .

The code above also explains why the `characterSetResults` property cannot be set to `utf8mb4` and provides an alternative solution where you can set `characterSetResults` to `null`.

### Test code

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * @author fade
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309";
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("user", "root");
        properties.put("password", "*******");
        // for jdbc 8.0.29
        properties.put("characterSetResults", "utf8mb4");
        // for jdbc 8.0.25
        // properties.put("characterSetResults", "utf8mb4");
        // properties.put("characterSetResults", "UTF-8");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character\\\\_set\\\\_%';");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.print(resultSet.getString(1) + " : ");
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString(2));
        }
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM performance_schema.session_variables\n" +
                "WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN (\n" +
                "  'character_set_client', 'character_set_connection',\n" +
                "  'character_set_results', 'collation_connection'\n" +
                ") ORDER BY VARIABLE_NAME;");
        System.out.println("**************************************************");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.print(resultSet.getString(1) + " : ");
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString(2));
        }
    }

}
```

### Conclusion

**The problem is caused by jdbc driver. The solutions are as below.**

- **Set `characterSetResults` to `null` in DataGrip Data Sources Dialog**
- **Change DataGrip jdbc driver version to `8.0.29` and set `characterSetResults` to `utf8mb4` in DataGrip Data Sources Dialog (I had tested it with MySQL `8.0.29`)**

Comment: Got it working (DataGrip 2023.2.3, MySQL Server 8.0.35, MySQL Driver 8.0.25). **1.** Choose the particular **Data Source** and go to the [**Advanced tab**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html#advancedTab). **2.** Find **characterSetResults** and set its value to **null**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in DataGrip yet, but might be solved after implementing this feature: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2606

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the context. Could you elaborate? Do I have to set a session variable? If so, which one?